# Wordpress Queries to count updates post per day in specific categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

Anyone know how to count updates post per day (example: in this day/date) in specific categories with wordpress query ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand your question, do you want a count of posts in a specific category posted on a specific day/date?

In this case, you can just create an instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and pass in the [time parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) and [categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) you want you look at.

Something like,

```
<?php
$today = getdate();
$args = array('year' => $today["year"], 'monthnum' => $today["mon"], 'day' => $today["mday"], 'category_name' => 'Uncategorized');
$search = new WP_Query($args);
$count = $search->found_posts;
?>
```

If you want to return posts based on the modified date (you state count updates post per day, which I don't understand), then you need to add a 'posts_where' filter instead of the time parameters of args.

See the time parameters link above for sample code and explanations on using this - but in slightly modifying one of their examples you can create something like this.

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
$where .= " AND post_modified >= '2010-03-01' AND post_modified < '2010-03-16'";
return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Comment: thanks for helping, that's was i'm lookin' for... but i was solve it by my own code.